# Python, string , integer

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a string variable:

```
str1 = '0000120000210000'
```

I want to convert the string into an integer without losing the first 4 zero characters. In other words, I want the integer variable to also store the first 4 zero digits as part of the integer.

I tried the `int()` function, but I'm not able to retain the first four digits.

Comment: That's simply cannot be done.. `integer` value does not store the leading zero's, because there can be any number of them. But if you want to print it like that, that can be done by formatting output..

Comment: also leading 0s mean "octal" numbers.

Comment: @PrototypeStark: Only in Python 2.

Comment: Adding to @RohitJain's correct comment (which should be an answer IMO), you should never store a number as an integer unless you're planning on doing arithmetic with it. In all other cases, they should be stored as strings.

Comment: @TimPietzcker. Added. I think will append your comment too there. It's worth knowing. :)

Comment: It sounds like a strange requirement. Maybe you want to post the bigger problem you are trying to solve so people can suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *two* integers, one to store the width of the number, and the other to store the number itself:

```
kw = len(s)
k = int(s)
```

To put the number back together in a string, use `format`:

```
print '{:0{width}}'.format(k, width=kw) # prints 0000120000210000
```

But, in general, you should not store identifiers (such as credit card numbers, student IDs, etc.) as integers, even if they appear to be. Numbers in these contexts should only be used if you need to do arithmetic, and you don't usually do arithmetic with identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

What you want simply cannot be done.. Integer value does not store the leading zero's, because there can be any number of them. So, it can't be said how many to store.

But if you want to `print` it like that, that can be done by `formatting output`.

**EDIT**: -

Added **@TimPietzcker's** comment from OP to make complete answer: -

You should never store a number as an integer unless you're planning on doing arithmetic with it. In all other cases, they should be stored as strings